# How to use "two selfs" in XSLT XPath query?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="live/file[not(deleted/file[@id=@id])]"/>
```

This doesn't work, obviously. The logic here is that I'm trying to select all files that don't have `/deleted/file` elements where `@id` equals to the `@id` of original object. This is XML:

```
<root>
  <live>
    <file id='a'/>
    <file id='b'/>
    <file id='c'/>
  </live>
  <deleted>
    <file id='b'/>
  </deleted>
</root>
```

The problem is that this statement is wrong: `@id=@id`, since they both are in the same axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely use keys here, both for clarity and for performance.

```
<xsl:key name="deleted-ids" match="deleted/file" use="@id"/>
```

then

```
<xsl:template match="live/file[not(key('deleted-ids', @id))]">
    [<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>]
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
live/file[not(@id=../../deleted/file/@id)]
```

Comment: "live/file[not(@id=../../deleted/file/@id)]" gives the expected result. "live/file[not(../../deleted/file[@id=current()/@id])]" will not work, because meaning of "current()" is already different at the moment of calling.

Comment: Huh? The second version works fine for me. Of course, you'll need to modify how you're selecting `file` elements, but given that, it's OK.

Comment: Oh, duh, shouldn't be using `current()` in a match pattern, even though some processors let it fly. I make this mistake all the time. Will remove.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="live/file[not(@id = ../../deleted/file/@id)]"/>
```

However, using a **key** is better for this type of matching.

Comment: This definitely *does not* work. The `!=` performs an existential comparison. That is, it will return true when there are *any* `deleted` files that don't match the current one. So, when there is more than one `deleted` item then it's going to return everything.

Comment: In other words, it is asking "does there *exist* a deleted file that does not have the current `@id`" which is not the same as asking "is it the case that *no* deleted files have the current `@id`". This will only appear to work on the given example, but will fail when there are more deleted elements.

Comment: @lwburk You are absolutely correct. I tested this with not() and inadvertently pasted the non-working != version which I have discarded earlier for the exact reason you mention.